# deploymentServiceAccountName does not work for schedules in spring cloud dataflow

Tags: spring, spring-cloud-dataflow, spring-cloud-task, spring-cloud-deployer-kubernetes

I am using spring cloud dataflow for spring batches(with remote partitioning) wrapped with spring cloud task, deployed in kubernetes. I have also created a service account for the same. The batch runs fine when I use the *launch* option on tasks tab in SCDF UI. But when I try *schedule* option in the SCDF UI, it seems to not consider the configured service account name and it gives the below error

```
io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.KubernetesClientException: Failure executing: GET at: https://<IP>/api/v1/namespaces/test/pods/batchsampleappworker-aeghj644g. Message: Forbidden!Configured service account doesn't have access. Service account may have been revoked. pods "batchsampleappworker-j3ljqq3de9" is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:test:default" cannot get resource "pods" in API group "" in the namespace "test".
```

Below is a sample config provided in SCDF server configuration

```
data:
  application.yaml: |-
    spring:
      cloud:
        dataflow:
          task:
            platform:
              kubernetes:
                accounts:
                  default:
                    deploymentServiceAccountName: myserviceaccountname
```

Please shed some light on this issue and help me getting this resolved

Answer (score 1):

On my way exploring the solution for the problem, I came across [this github page](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow/blob/main/spring-cloud-dataflow-docs/src/main/asciidoc/configuration-kubernetes.adoc) where it was suggested to add either

```
env:
- name: SPRING_CLOUD_SCHEDULER_KUBERNETES_TASK_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_NAME
  value: myserviceaccountname
```

to the deployment of SCDF server or,

```
deployer.kubernetes.taskServiceAccountName=myserviceaccountname
```

to the individual schedule while creating it. Unfortunately, neither of them worked for me but triggered me to try out with the below per schedule created and it worked for me.

```
scheduler.kubernetes.taskServiceAccountName=myserviceaccountname
```

It will be great if someone help me in explaining why the first option - updating deployment did not work?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is quite an old question, but I had the same problem recently and was able to solve it like with an entry like this in my tasks deployment yaml:

```
deployer.<task-name>.kubernetes.taskServiceAccountName=<service-account>
```

The task name was missing in the above answer. Possibly it would also work with

```
deployer.*.kubernetes.taskServiceAccountName=<service-account>
```